# What is the source of the song Od Yishama?

Tags: sources-mekorot, music

What is the source of the popular song Od Yeshama?

I tried searching for "עוד ישמע בְּעָרֵי יְהוּדָה וּבְחֻצוֹת" and did not find anything.

I am asking because I was wondering if it should be pronounced  יְרוּשָׁלַ‍ִם or  יְרוּשָׁלַ‍ִים? I was surprised that typing either into google did not yield the Posuk. I am now curious about the source for the song and the proper pronunciation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The source is [Yirmiyahu 33:10-11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1133.htm)

Comment: Aha, so it is not a continuous phrase in the posukim. That is what I could not easily find it via google.

When people sing it, I hear "וּבְחֻצוֹת יְרוּשָׁלַים", but it clearly says "יְרוּשָׁלִַם". Is it being sung incorrectly?

Comment: The vowels of יְרוּשָׁלִַם are there to indicate that you should read it as if it were יְרוּשָׁלַיִם.